# If I create a database in MySQL using terminal, should it show under my databases in PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, database, terminal, phpmyadmin

Total beginner to the world of MySQL and PHP (using MAMP).

Very simple question which I can not seem to find the answer to anywhere.

I have created a MySQL database (called user_info) in terminal under the 'root' user on 'localhost' with all permissions/privileges granted, when I access PhpMyAdmin as root user on localhost (which is what it says under the database server pane) I can't see the database I created in terminal in the left hand pane or under the databases tab of PhpMyAdmin ?

The question is really whether the databases created in terminal should reflect in the databases section in PhpMyAdmin or is this a total mis-understanding of the way it all works on my part ?

Any advice or explanation would be greatly appreciated !

Kind regards

Comment: It should show. In face it does. Was your database created successfully in the terminal? Was it listed among other databases when you used `show databases;` in terminal?

Comment: I thought this was the case... Yes it was successfully created in terminal as when I check SHOW DATABASES; it is in my list of db's, however it is not in the databases in PhpMyConfig. I have also checked the config.default.php, config.php and config.inc.php for the hide_db property and this is all fine... I'm really quite stumped with this whole thing. I have experience in object oriented languages and thought this would be a breeze but I appear to have fallen at the first hurdle and can't seem to figure this out ?

Comment: I am a Windows user,  so not sure about Mac, but try going into your mamp folder where it is installed and there, find the folder named `mysql` and then `data`. Within this folder there should be subfolders for every database you create. Is your `user_info` database listed there? That should be a file named `user_info`. Also try creating a database from your phpMyAdmin UI and check if it shows in your terminal under `show databases;` query.

Comment: From the command line client, type `'SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name = "datadir"'` and note the path it shows; then run the same command from the SQL tab of phpMyAdmin (or click the Variables tab at the top and search for it, either will give you the same result). Do they match?

Comment: In command line it shows the dir /usr/local/mysql/data/. In phpMyAdmin it shows the dir /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/. So what does this mean ?

Comment: Can anybody shed any light on this ?

Comment: @JulesHarrison sorry for the delay; it seems sometimes Stack Overflow reply notifications don't get through. I've added an answer below, hopefully it still helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two MySQL installations on your Mac. MAMP comes with MySQL and it looks like you also installed another MySQL outside of MAMP. This explains the two different data directories -- the MAMP MySQL is using `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/` and the other installation is using 'usr/local/mysql/data/`.

Pick one to keep and remove the other one. You can force your client to connect to whichever one you want, by specifying the port or socket each one is using to listen for connections, but unless you have a specific reason for wanting to run two MySQL instances, it's going to be less confusing to remove one. Just make sure you don't have any stored data that you wish to save (or export/dump it to SQL first).

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue when playing with MAMP.
And I finally find out that I have two MySQL installations on my Mac, just like Issac said.
One is installed individually, under /usr/local/mysql, and the other is installed together with MAMP, under /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
So to see what is seen in phpmyadmin, I need to connect with the MAMP one.
hope this helps.